# Error al ingresar números en celda de datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un datagridview que se carga mediante una query de SQL que tiene varias columnas,
Una de estas columnas carga un valor que es entero y como el datagridview queda disponible para que el usuario modifique los datos, cuando intenta ingresar alguna letra sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

========================================

Existe alguna forma de hacer para que el usuario solo tenga habilitada las teclas numéricas o que en su defecto, si es que escribe una letra la celda quede vacía para que no salte este error?

Comment: Alex, bienvenid@ a SOes. Considera incluir un [mcve] en tu pregunta para que puedas obtener una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario que agregues un evento a la columna que capture la entrada de tecla del usuario y permita unicamente números. Para ello primero declaras el evento en el GridView de la siguiente forma:

```
    private void MiDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        //MiDataGridView es el nombre del DataGridView que estás utilizando.
        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
        if (MiDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3) //Columna que solo acepta números
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
            }
        }
    }
```

Donde e.Control contiene el control que está dentro de la columna en este caso un DataGridViewTextBoxColumn para poder agregarle el evento  Column1_KeyPress hacemos un CAST

```
    //hacemos un cast e.Control a un TextBox
    // y lo asignamos a una nueva instancia de tipo TextBox llamada tb
    TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
```

Y posteriormente declaras el evento Column1_KeyPress de la columna que acabas de asignar:

```
    private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: En mi caso, esta funciona inhabilitando a que el usuario pueda ingresar solo números enteros, cual es la función que cumple la variable "TB", para comprender un poco la lógica del código? De ante mano muchas gracias!

Comment: Editaré la publicación para explicar este detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Si existe una forma, al cargar tu tabla, le adjuntas el evento, ejemplo:

```
private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.tablaFuente = new DataTable(NombreTabla);

            tablaFuente.ColumnChanged += tablaFuente_Cambia; // handler para cuando una columna se cambia

            //Teniendo en cuenta que existe dataGridView1 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tablaFuente;

    }

void tablaFuente_Cambia(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.ProposedValue);

            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Escribe un número");
            }
        }
```